# SendKeys to click on a dialog box button in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access 2013. I searched a variety of online resources. I thought SendKeys was the answer.

Once per quarter, my client will receive an updated Access database.  All table names should be identical each quarter.  I want them to run a macro, specify the location of the new file, and then the macro updates the linked tables and executes all other queries I’ve built (I have the last part working).
The part I have not be able to get working is to check the “Always prompt for a new location box”, check the “select all” box and click OK (and then click OK and close after the client specifies the new file location).  Below is the code I am using.

```vb
Function Open_LinkedTableManager()

    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdLinkedTableManager 'this step works fine

    'the following lines, up until Application.Run don’t appear to be
    'doing anything.  The code will run, but I have to manually execute
    'each of the steps I am trying to automate before it gets to the
    'Application.Run step

    SendKeys "%a", True ' also tried SendKeys "%(a)" and "+a", "a", etc,
    'True; Alt+a checks the "Always prompt for a new location box” 
      SendKeys "%s", True ' also tried SendKeys "%(s)", True; Alt+s checks the "select all"         'box 
      SendKeys "{Enter}" ' then user specifies location of new file 
      SendKeys "{Enter}" ' click OK after receiving message "All selected linked tables        'were successfully refreshed" 
      ' click Close to close linked table manager and proceed to the next step below (not 'sure how to do this)

    Application.Run ("Update_all_queries") ' this is working;

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If sending to yourself then try DoEvents after each sendkey.

**DoEvents Function**

Yields execution so that the operating system can process other events.

Syntax

```
DoEvents( )
```

Remarks

The DoEvents function returns an Integer representing the number of open forms in stand-alone versions of Visual Basic, such as Visual Basic, Professional Edition. DoEvents returns zero in all other applications.

DoEvents passes control to the operating system. Control is returned after the operating system has finished processing the events in its queue and all keys in the SendKeys queue have been sent.

DoEvents is most useful for simple things like allowing a user to cancel a process after it has started, for example a search for a file. For long-running processes, yielding the processor is better accomplished by using a Timer or delegating the task to an ActiveX EXE component.. In the latter case, the task can continue completely independent of your application, and the operating system takes case of multitasking and time slicing.

Caution   Any time you temporarily yield the processor within an event procedure, make sure the procedure is not executed again from a different part of your code before the first call returns; this could cause unpredictable results. In addition, do not use DoEvents if other applications could possibly interact with your procedure in unforeseen ways during the time you have yielded control.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I tried that (a variety of ways) and I haven't been able to make that work.  I still have to manually do all the steps I am trying to automate with SendKeys.  I read somewhere else that the vba code won't execute while a dialog box is open.  Not sure if there is a way around that, but that seems to be what is happening here.  Perhaps the DoEvents and SendKeys commands are getting executed, but not until after I close the dialog box and hence they are not serving my intended purpose.

Comment: Try to use the wshshell sendkeys, it takes a window title rather than vba's Active Window. If still a problem use wshshell's run method to spin it out as a vbs file. Remember in vbs you don't declare as DataType (so just dim A) and you have to use set = createobject("Object.Type").

Comment: `Set WShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")` In VBA you can add as a reference and early bind.

Comment: Thanks again.  I tried it and wasn't able to get it to work.  It seems nothing will execute after DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdLinkedTableManager until I close that box.  I am not sure if there is another way to call the table manager and allow additional commands to be executed while it is open.  I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved your dilemma. All I needed to do was place the sendkey statements before the call to to the linked tabled manager. See Below - Worked Great For Me! I was also able to add all of the commands in your order and they worked great. Good luck, hope this helped. Let me know. Adam

PS: If you have many tables to change the path on, this will be painful for the user for every table you are forcing them to have to set the path for.

```
SendKeys "%s", 1

DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdLinkedTableManager
```